# How to make create big checkboxes with images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I create big checkboxes with an image like this:

[image]

Comment: This might help, good article : http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of jquery plugins that can help you do this.

for example try these links:

http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/

http://wpleet.com/493-12-cool-javascript-jquery-checkbox-replacement-you-shouldnt-miss/